# Data model for sparse time series data

Tags: orientdb

First of all I'm using OrientDB 2.1.4 and I'm building an API to show some graph data series. I have the following dataset of base salary updates:

```
Person   Base salary   Period
======   ===========   ======
John            1200   201411
John            1300   201503
John            1500   201508
Megan           1000   201410
Megan           1100   201501
```

Person is class V. I want to know which model type suits me the best to give me the following yearly report for one person to graph (eg. John):

```
Period   Base Salary
======   ===========
201501          1200 <= last updated salary: 1200 in 201411
201502          1200
201503          1300 <= here the base salary gets updated
201504          1300
201505          1300
201506          1300
201507          1300
201508          1500 <= and here again
201509          1500
201510          1500
201511          1500
201512          1500
```

So far I've tried embeddedLists in Person and LinkedLists, but I can't figure out how to retrieve the last known value of a base salary for a period which has no linked data.

The best I've achieved so far is to model Period and BaseSalary as class V, and creating edges between them: Person -> BaseSalary -> Period eg. John -> 1200 -> 201411, but still don't know how to get the value 1200 between periods 201411 and 201502 using this model.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Rod

Comment: `Person -> BaseSalary -> Period` seems pretty good to me. You could save the salary to each period it was active for, or you could save the period a salary was active from. Whichever way you do it would have an effect on your queries. I have a question for you though, when you select a salary from a range of periods, do you want to select the last salary, the highest value salary, or all the salaries in order like your list above? And will you be selecting the salary for 1 person, or multiple people?

Comment: When I select only 1 person, I want to show all the salaries for each period. If he/she doesn't have any change for one period it must show the last one available. However if I choose the whole dataset for analysis I want to show de average value between a range of periods. This last query is going ok.